# How to read multiple files and save a single output with pandas use command line arguments

Tags: pandas

I have multiple files in TXT format how to get all the values ​​with a single output Merge values ​​into a single file use command line arguments in pandas

like this:

```
python3 file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import socket, struct
import os
import glob
import sys

try:
    file = sys.argv[1]
except Exception:
    print("Usage: python3 {} [file]".format(sys.argv[0]))
    sys.exit()

os.chdir('/Users/roc/Desktop/js/projj')
fileList = glob.glob('*.txt')
appended_data = []
for file in fileList:
    pdd = pd.read_csv(file,header=None,sep='|',error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False,skiprows=[0],names=['Name','Code','Ipv', 'Ip','Range','Date', 'Category'],low_memory=False)
    df = pdd[pdd['Ipv'].str.contains("ipv4") & pdd['Ip'].str.contains('[0-9]')]
    appended_data.append(df)
appended_data = pd.concat(appended_data)
df = pd.DataFrame(appended_data)
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
def ip2int(ip):
    packedIP = socket.inet_aton(ip)
    return struct.unpack("!L", packedIP)[0]
df['Ip'] = df.Ip.apply(ip2int)
df['Range'] = df.groupby(['Code'])['Range'].transform('sum').fillna(0).astype(int)
k = df[['Ip', 'Range', 'Code']].dropna()
df2 = k.drop_duplicates(subset=['Range'])
result_df =df2.sort_values('Range', ascending=True)    
print(result_df.to_csv("/Users/roc/Desktop/js/projj/delegated2.txt",sep=' ', index=False, header=False))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Use the below to iterate through a folder and append all files to a single dataframe*

```
import os
import glob
os.chdir('C:\\path_to_folder\\')
Filelist = glob.glob('*.txt')
appended_data = []
for file in FileList:
    pdd = pd.read_csv(file,header=None,sep='|',error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False,skiprows=[0],names=['Name','Code','Ipv', 'Ip','Range','Date', 'Category'],low_memory=False)
    df = pdd[pdd['Ipv'].str.contains("ipv4") & pdd['Ip'].str.contains('[0-9]')] 
    appended_data.append(df)
appended_data = pd.concat(appended_data)
df = pd.DataFrame(appended_data)
```

Once you have the `df` which is combined of all the data from all files, use the next part of the code:

```
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None 
def ip2int(ip): 
    packedIP = socket.inet_aton(ip) 
    return struct.unpack("!L", packedIP)[0] 
df['Ip'] = df.Ip.apply(ip2int) df['Range'] = df.groupby(['Code'])['Range'].transform('sum').fillna(0).astype(int) 
k = df[['Ip', 'Range', 'Code']].dropna() 
df2 = k.drop_duplicates(subset=['Range']) 
result_df =df2.sort_values('Range', ascending=True)
result_df.to_csv("/Users/roc/Desktop/output.txt",sep=' ', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: Used for loops name file? or file path name `pd.read_csv(filename` <-(file)

Comment: @warezers so you have to set up the sys.arg to define the folder path, and the script above takes all files which is .txt from that folder

Comment: When I run the command line python3 example.py file1.txt file2.txt, it shows some of its errors `raise ValueError('No objects to concatenate')
ValueError: No objects to concatenate`

Comment: @warezers which line? i had put `filename` instead of `file` under read csv just fixed it.  The idea is if you are able to set up your arg so that it returns a folder and pass it under `os.chdir()` , rest the code will work

Comment: @warezers i dont think you need the try and except statement if you want to loop through all files in the folder. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187029/discussion-between-warezers-and-anky-91).